# After escaping html chars with CakePHP's Santiize::html() is it secure to unescape chars like *() inorder for the markdown parser to work?

Tags: cakephp, markdown

Before displaying user posts I run them though Sanitize::html() to escape all html. But it escapes some of the chars that are used for the Markdown parser.

**This is what I want:**
I'm testing this markdown. Try [clicking](http://www.google.com) here

**This is what I get:**
I'm testing this markdown. Try [clicking](http://www.google.com&#41; here

So I'm wondering if it is okay to unescape the markdown chars or is that going to leave me open to some XSS exploit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown is a bit more complex than just escaping some characters (There's a reason there is a *parser* for it). The solution in this case would be to run the input through the Markdown parser first (I'm not sure if you use a PHP markdown parser, or something else), then through the sanitizer.

Good luck!